# Intel fortran on vs2013 and vs2015 possible?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, fortran, intel-fortran

I run Visual Studio 2013 with Intel Fortran integrated.
Now I switch to VS 2015. Can I  integrate the same Fortran installation in VS2015 too? How?

or must I reinstall Intel Fortran and integrate with only VS 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current release of Intel Visual Fortran (16.0) will integrate with all versions of Visual Studio from 2010 through to 2015, at the same time.

After installing a new version of Visual Studio you will need to reinstall Intel Visual Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in vs2019. After install, oneAPI-Base Toolkit and oneAPI-HPC Toolkit search FortranCompilerPkgs.vsix and intall it.